# Ubuntu powering off in 21.10. Saying " Your system will power off in 60 seconds". Need help

Tags: 21.10

I updated my Ubuntu from 20.04 to 21.10 yesterday. Now I am receiving a message saying "Your system will power off in 60 seconds." and there are 2 options, one is cancel and second is Power off. When I hit the cancel button, the PC immediately turned off. And again turned on the pc and ran journal in terminal and found this:

```
the_cactus_knox@Cactus-Knox:~$ journalctl -b-0
-- Journal begins at Mon 2022-01-10 09:37:55 IST, ends at Wed 2022-03-23 15:32:>
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revis>
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel: Linux version 5.13.0-37-generic (buildd@lcy>
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.13>
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x>
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'S>
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'A>
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x008: 'M>
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x010: 'M>
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_siz>
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[3]:  832, xstate_siz>
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[4]:  896, xstate_siz>
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel: x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x1f, cont>
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000>
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x000000>
Jan 10 09:37:55 Cactus-Knox kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000>
...skipping...
Mar 23 15:31:45 Cactus-Knox thermald[897]: Unable to find a sensor for \_SB_.PC>
Mar 23 15:31:45 Cactus-Knox thermald[897]: Unable to find a sensor for \_SB_.PC>
Mar 23 15:31:49 Cactus-Knox thermald[897]: Unable to find a sensor for \_SB_.PC>
Mar 23 15:31:49 Cactus-Knox thermald[897]: Unable to find a sensor for \_SB_.PC>
Mar 23 15:31:53 Cactus-Knox thermald[897]: Unable to find a sensor for \_SB_.PC>
Mar 23 15:31:53 Cactus-Knox thermald[897]: Unable to find a sensor for \_SB_.PC>
Mar 23 15:31:54 Cactus-Knox systemd[3579]: Started Application launched by gsd->
Mar 23 15:31:54 Cactus-Knox dbus-daemon[3592]: [session uid=1000 pid=3592] Acti>
Mar 23 15:31:54 Cactus-Knox systemd[3579]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Mar 23 15:31:54 Cactus-Knox gnome-terminal-server[25372]: Display does not supp>
Mar 23 15:31:54 Cactus-Knox dbus-daemon[3592]: [session uid=1000 pid=3592] Succ>
Mar 23 15:31:54 Cactus-Knox systemd[3579]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Mar 23 15:31:54 Cactus-Knox systemd[3579]: Started VTE child process 25390 laun>
Mar 23 15:31:57 Cactus-Knox thermald[897]: Unable to find a sensor for \_SB_.PC>
Mar 23 15:31:57 Cactus-Knox thermald[897]: Unable to find a sensor for \_SB_.PC>
Mar 23 15:32:01 Cactus-Knox thermald[897]: Unable to find a sensor for \_SB_.PC>
Mar 23 15:32:01 Cactus-Knox thermald[897]: Unable to find a sensor for \_SB_.PC>
Mar 23 15:32:02 Cactus-Knox kernel: IPv6: MLD: clamping QRV from 1 to 2!
Mar 23 15:32:05 Cactus-Knox thermald[897]: Unable to find a sensor for \_SB_.PC>
Mar 23 15:32:05 Cactus-Knox thermald[897]: Unable to find a sensor for \_SB_.PC>
Mar 23 15:32:09 Cactus-Knox kernel: IPv6: MLD: clamping QRV from 1 to 2!
Mar 23 15:32:09 Cactus-Knox thermald[897]: Unable to find a sensor for \_SB_.PC>
Mar 23 15:32:09 Cactus-Knox thermald[897]: Unable to find a sensor for \_SB_.PC>
lines 3255-3277/3277 (END)
```

here is what I got for the command Sensors

```
the_cactus_knox@Cactus-Knox:~$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +45.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:     2300 RPM

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          14.57 V  

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +42.0°C  

pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +44.0°C  

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +47.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)
```

This is what it showed when I received the message again.
There is no change in temperature. They are almost same. This is what it showed just now

```
the_cactus_knox@Cactus-Knox:~$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +44.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +44.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +42.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:     2200 RPM

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          14.57 V  

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +46.0°C  

pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +41.0°C  

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +43.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)
```

PS: Pressing the esc key closes the dialogue window without switching off the PC.

Comment: Is your system a notebook (laptop) with a failing battery? Please, also `sudo apt install lm-sensors` and give us the output of the `sensors` command. Please, [edit] your question to add any information requested in comments.

Comment: Yes, I use a laptop, but the battery is good. There is no problem with the battery.

Comment: I assume that when you get that message, you immediately connect your laptop to power (just in case...) And also please  check the temperature of the "CPU Cores" when you get that message.

Comment: I added the changes in the question.

Comment: It looks like something is activating the shutdown process, just like as if you clicked the shutdown button on screen or pressed the power button of your computer. Maybe related to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/495889/how-to-disable-the-feature-of-automatic-system-shutdown-in-60-seconds

Comment: Thank you. Could you also help me out with another question that I just uploaded.